# regex groups with uneven number of groups

Tags: regex, regex-group, python-re

I'm not good with terms used in regex, so picking a suitable title for this question is some how difficult for me, so feel free the suggest a good title.

but anyway I have this txt and regex expression

```
import re
txt = """
%power {s}
shop %power {w}
%electricity {t}
""".replace('\n',' ')
x = re.findall("((\%?\w+\s)*)\{([^\}]*)\}",txt)
```

the result is

`[('%power ', '%power ', 's'), ('shop %power ', '%power ', 'w'), ('%electricity ', '%electricity ', 't')]`
but I was intended to get

`[('%power ', 's'), ('shop ', '%power ', 'w'), ('%electricity ', 't')]` so how can I achieve the desired?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `pip install regex` and then use

```py
import regex
txt = """
%power {s}
shop %power ow {w}
%electricity {t}
""".replace('\n',' ')
x = regex.finditer(r"(%?\w+\s)*\{([^{}]*)}", txt)
z = [tuple(y.captures(1) + y.captures(2)) for y in x] 
print(z)
```

See the [Python demo](https://tio.run/##TY3LCoMwEADv@YolICYqQttz6YeoBbFrG7BJWFd8hHy7ldJDj3OYGb/yy9nLvpu3d8RA@MRF8MJwBSmlSLybkSCMUYwv5@HHboYwR5HggB2T6QyvEDiKQykJ/dB2qNLapkUKqRbLEfuGy97Yh2EkRVIlt3rO61FndVDVPcQm01EWcLy12A6j4skPqNayaz1PhKM6acjhj89aQ@8IVjAWlgaEJ2NZbXrfPw).

Output:

```
[('%power ', 's'), ('shop ', '%power ', 'ow ', 'w'), ('%electricity ', 't')]
```

**NOTE on `regex.finditer` usage**

The `regex.finditer` method returns an *iterable*, not a list. It has an implication that you [cannot re-use](https://tio.run/##lY/NasMwEITvfoqJikFKTKDtNabX9hniFIK7qQWOJFZr/CP87K4oOfTa4w7zzceGWTrvXrfN3oNnAdM3TYVMghpKqTL4kRgprkDsfMAj8CPSmLOSemqFbWtlRpI1I8WU0d@Z4826LyvEmpUu35rx0ESzb5I@f6b1sjerqpBNpghsnWicZQg96fnYXoMMTFE/Gxzw534xBjfPmGEdpgtMsWTZv7mHcKmgTqe6xjsxVVhgI64OdA/5md5G2SmDJ3zEOBC63Nlt2w8) the `x` inside a list comprehension.
In order to re-use the contents of `x`, either [convert it to a list](https://tio.run/##lY3BCoJAFEX3fsVlQJhnIVTr6EO0IGzKAXOGNy/UBr/dhnDRtuU9cO7xk7SuPyyLfXrHAjYPM2YyCo5QSuXeDYYRwwyE1nmswA2IQ2K56UwjbBsrE6LMScnGpHY2iP5@lXfb36wY1qx0fqqHTR2oqKOuLnE@FzSrLVKOKPNse9Go5OU7o6eyuXp5sQl6R9jgZ@@JcHeMCbbHeAZl75T821uDb1qWDw) (`list(x)`), or use the approach above, use it only once to get the necessary output structure, and do whatever you need with the result.

Comment: I haven't heard of `regex` (https://pypi.org/project/regex/) over `re` before? Is it widely used?

Comment: I think u should add if they print it once the would lose the `z`!

Comment: @AndyLester It is used by everyone who needs full regex power in Python.

Comment: @FarhangAmaji [I do not lose anything](https://tio.run/##TY3NasMwEITv@xSLwFibBEPbWyH0QeIUgrppBK4k1hv8I/TsrtL20Ll9M8xMWvQWw8u2@a8URVH4k2fQWfGIxhhoUpxYMI8FxltM@MdxwjwVaHhgp@Kd1wWzFqiVTjgNF8e27UN7aLElmOvYz3B39eHDK4sVY5u3ftr3I@36bE/vuZx3VMwB6zfBWhsnvaeB7dK5S9K78GifCPf4j5@J8BoFF/QB5zNCEh/UrgQP1z3c9RWw6jdwtG3f).

Comment: ```import regex

txt = """ %power {s}
 shop %power ow {w}
 %electricity {t} """.replace('\n',' ')
x = regex.finditer(r"(%?\w+\s)*\{([^{}]*)}", txt)
print( [tuple(y.captures(1) + y.captures(2)) for y in x] )
z = [tuple(y.captures(1) + y.captures(2)) for y in x] 
print(z)``` copy and paste it and separate lines of code  and put it in `tio.run/`

Comment: [https://tio.run/##lY3BasJAFEX38xWXgZB5KoHquvghRkHSpw6kM8PLkyQO@fY0LQrdurwH7jlp1FsMu3n23ymKQvjKgzE6KD5hrUWRYs@C3E0G3S2mF4g9cr@wgltuVHzjdUTW6fdUCaf23LAr61BuSpRkhkX3564uPnx5ZXFiXbGv@3Xd0arO7nDK03FFk91gqZNJ4oM6HPSeWnZj1ZyT3oU790FY49/eEuESBSN8wHAEmccSe//3LD5onn8A]

Comment: But the `regex.finditer` returns an iterator, not a list. You get an empty list because you try to access an iterator whose index is at the end. Of course you need to get all matches into a list and then reuse the contents.